# DateTimeParseException on java 11 but not on java 8

Tags: java, dateparser

Hello when I run the following code using **java 8** all works fine

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       LocalDate date =  LocalDate.parse("24ENE1982", new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().parseCaseInsensitive()
                .appendPattern("ddMMMyyyy")
                .toFormatter(new Locale("es", "ES")));
        System.out.println("Hello world! " + date);
    }
```

but fail with **java 11**

More specific

> java 11.0.19 2023-04-18 LTS Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9
> (build 11.0.19+9-LTS-224) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9
> (build 11.0.19+9-LTS-224, mixed mode)

If I use **java 18** works too.

Any idea to solve this issue without upgrade or downgrade the java version

I have tried to set the Locale using

```
Locale.forLanguageTag("es-ES")
```

and

```
new Locale("es", "ES")
```

But with no changes

Expected value

```
Hello world! 1982-01-24
```

but an exception sin thrown

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '24ENE1982' could not be parsed at index 2
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2046)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:428)
    at Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

Comment: @Jens, it works too in 17.0.2 (tested in `jshell`)

Comment: Don't just say it "fails". Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should provide [complete error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough)

Comment: Sorry ment *java11*

Comment: Just on suspicion, but if it worked in 8 and 17 and not in 11, you might be looking for a fixed bug report. Regarding your use of the `Locale` objects: how did you make use of the result of those calls? That produces a `Locale` object, but without using it or setting it somewhere, it wouldn't be applied.

Comment: ( try `new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().parseCaseInsensitive().appendPattern("ddMMMyyyy").toFormatter(new Locale("es", "ES")).format(LocalDate.of(1982,1,24))` to see what format is expected - apparently the date constants for that version got some errors {also note that `MMM` does not mean exactly 3 letters, it just so happen for most `Locale`s } )

Comment: Printing out `month.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, locale))` for every Month constant in Java 11 reveals that the Spanish short month names all have a period at the end.

Comment: Fails for me too in 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, in Java 11 the short month names have a trailing dot in Spanish.  This is the cause of the problem, as a solution you could use a `DateTimeFormatter` with custom month names derived from the "official" ones but without any dot.  The following example works with Java 8, Java 11 and Java 17.

```java
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale locale = new Locale("es", "ES");

        Map<Long, String> months = new HashMap<>();
        for (Month m : Month.values()) {
            months.put(Long.valueOf(m.getValue()),
                       m.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, locale).replace(".", ""));
        }                         

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                .appendPattern("dd")
                .appendText(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, months)
                .appendPattern("yyyy")
                .toFormatter(locale);
        
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("24ENE1982", formatter);
        System.out.println("Hello world! " + date);
    }

}
```

Read also about [Locale Data Providers](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-suported-locales.html#providers) at oracle.com.